# Take a random number inside an array and every time the browser reload it changes

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I did this project in Angular that uses the TMDB API, the project is almost finished, but I wanted to make a change that every time the browser was reloaded, the background image (backdrop_path) and the other items changed.
At the moment this information is manual coming from the TMDB API.
Grateful

```js
Service *****

 getComedy(): Observable<Movies> {
    return this.http.get<Movies>(`${this.url}${endpoint.comedy}`, { params } )
  }
```

```html
Component HEADER ****

<div class="header__banner" [ngStyle]="{'background' : 'url(' + headerBGUrl + ')'}">
      <div class="featured--horizontal">
        <div class="featured--vertical"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="info">
          <div class="title">
            <h2>{{ comedy.results[5].title }}</h2> 
            <span class="points">Nota: </span>
            <span class="points">{{ comedy.results[5].popularity | number:'1.1-1'}}</span> 
            <span>{{ comedy.results[5].release_date | date:'yyyy' }}</span>
          </div>
          <p>{{ comedy.results[5].overview }}</p>
          <div class="info-btns">
            <button class="watchButton">► Assistir</button>
            <button class="listButton">+ Minha Lista</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    ****
Component Header Typescript *****


  subs: Subscription[] = []
  sticky!: boolean;

  comedy!: Movies;

  @ViewChild('stickHeader') header!: ElementRef;
  headerBGUrl!: any;
  
  constructor(public movies: ServiceApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subs.push(this.movies.getComedy().subscribe(data => {
      this.comedy = data;
      this.headerBGUrl = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original' + this.comedy.results[5].backdrop_path;
    }));
  }
```

Comment: Welcome Rod, what's the issue? What is not working? What did you try?

Comment: At the moment the images and text are being defined manually I'm having to put the number inside the array.
I wanted to make it random, and that every time you reload the page these images change

Comment: I wanted this number to be random and change every time the page is reloaded.
comedy.results[5].title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
...
randomNumber: number;
comedy!: Movies;
....
// this code is inside of your subscribe
this.comedy = data;
const min = 0;
// subtract one because arrays are zero index
const max = this.comedy.results.length - 1;
// create a random number between two values
this.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
// use randomNumber variable instead of 5
this.headerBGUrl = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original' + this.comedy.results[this.randomNumber].backdrop_path;
```

And everywhere in your HTML you have `5`, change it to `randomNumber`.